# How can I use variables that I find the value of in a loop outside of that loop?

Tags: java, loops, parameters, local, nested-loops

I want to use row and col as the parameters of my 2d array but cannot because I cant find a way because my variables are local to there loop. My question is how can I make the values i find for row and col the parameters of my array.

```
int list [] [] = new int [row] [col];
    boolean done = false;
    while (done = false)
    {
        for (int counter = 3; counter <= 15; counter++)
        {
            if (num%counter == 0)
            {
                int row = counter ;
                int col = num/counter;
                done = true;
            }          
        }
    }
```

Comment: `while (done = false)` should be `while (done == false)`

Comment: what if `num` has value 1?

Comment: @Lashane Or even better: `while (!done)`

Comment: Sorry to mention it here. My program makes it so the user so only input even values for num.

Comment: @RyanMiller ok, what if `num` has value 2?

Comment: Ok, I need to start counter at 1 then?

Comment: @RyanMiller if you start counter with 1 - then row will be 1, col = num, _always_, is it what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare them outside the loop:

```
    boolean done = false;
    int row = -1;
    int col = -1;
    while (done == false)
    {
        for (int counter = 3; counter <= 15; counter++)
        {
            if (num%counter == 0)
            {
                row = counter ;
                col = num/counter;
                done = true;
            }          
        }
    }
    int list [] [] = new int [row] [col];
```

Comment: Cannot reference a field before it is defined

Comment: Changed answer is better, it compiles now

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean done = false;
int row = -1;
int col = -1;

while (done == false)
{
    for (int counter = 3; counter <= 15; counter++)
    {
        if (num%counter == 0)
        {
            row = counter ;
            col = num/counter;
            done = true;
        }          
    }
}
System.out.println(row + " " + col);
int list [] [] = new int [row] [col];
```

Comment: You re still assigning a value to *done* every time you check the while loop

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it unless you create a new array cause static arrays are kinda static. Of course you can switch to `ArrayList` to evade these kind of misunderstandings.

Comment: The parameters of the array don't change. They just depend on what number the user inputs.